# No Images in ImageView using Glide making API call

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, retrofit2, android-glide

I've made a successful call to the api.  Everything is showing up except for the images.

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.moviespotter.R

class MoviesAdapter(val movies: List<Result>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoviesViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false)
        return MoviesViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoviesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        return holder.bind(movies[position])
    }
}

class MoviesViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    private val photo:ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_photo)
    private val title:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title)
    private val overview:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_overview)
    private val rating:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating)

    fun bind(movie: Result) {
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}").into(photo)
        title.text = "Title: " + movie.title
        overview.text = movie.overview
        rating.text = "User Score: " + movie.vote_average.toString()
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what is happening.  No errors.  The images are valid when I search for them with the url.  Nothing appears to be broken.

Here is the ImageView in the RelativeLayout:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/movie_photo"
                android:contentDescription="Movie Image" />
```

[image: screenshot]

---

Update:

The placeholders I added do appear:

```
Glide.with(itemView.context).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/rjkmN1dniUHVYAtwuV3Tji7FsDO.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.space_dog_laika1).into(photo)
```

[image: screenshot with placeholder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add placeholder to check if it's imageUrl's fault or the ImageView's.

```
Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.product_item).into(imageView)
```

Comment: The placeholder appeared.

Comment: so it's, URL's problem!

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  Turns out I was missing an 's'.

https instead of http.

```
Glide.with(itemView.context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/rjkmN1dniUHVYAtwuV3Tji7FsDO.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.space_dog_laika1).into(photo)
```

Comment: haha, Happens with life! happy coding!